# Honorary 'Rank' for this site?

Tags: discussion

I recently had the idea that, well, because this is a **Science Fiction** and Fantasy site, perhaps it would be fun if members could have a 'rank'!  I have just looked through the [Starfleet Ranks page on Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_ranks) and correlated some ranks with the privileges.  The idea is that once individuals achieve privileges, they are 'promoted' and can change their rank to the next level up.

The way I envisage it is that it would **not** be something forced on people - I appreciate that not everyone here is a Trekkie, but for those who are interested it might be a bit of fun to call themselves 'Captain [insert-handle-here]'.  People would add their rank, only if they wanted to of course, to the 'about me' section for their profile.

This is the rank system that I propose - any discussion would be greatly appreciated!

- [Cadet 4th class](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts) | Rep = 1
- [Cadet 3rd class](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) | Rep = 5
- [Cadet 2nd class](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) | Rep = 10
- [Cadet 1st class](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) | Rep = 15
- [Petty officer 3rd class](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) | Rep = 20
- [Petty officer 2nd class](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) | Rep = 50
- [Petty officer 1st class](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) | Rep = 75
- [Chief petty officer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) | Rep = 100
- [Senior chief petty officer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) | Rep = 125
- [Ensign](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) | Rep = 250
- [Lt Jr Grade](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) | Rep = 300
- [Lt](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) | Rep = 500
- [Lt Cmdr](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) | Rep = 1000
- [Cmdr](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) | Rep = 2000
- [Captain](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) | Rep = 2500
- [Fleet Captain](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) | Rep = 3000
- [Commodore](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) | Rep = 5000
- [Rear Admiral](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) | Rep = 10,000
- [Vice Admiral](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) | Rep = 15,000
- [Admiral](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) | Rep = 20,000
- Fleet Admiral | Moderator

Now, I appreciate this scheme may be a bit over the top, so we could have this second one instead which is based on milestones and moderation privileges:

- [Cadet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) | Rep = 10
- [Petty Officer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) | Rep = 15
- [Chief petty officer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) | Rep = 125
- [Ensign](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) | Rep = 250
- [Lt Jr Grade](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) | Rep = 500
- [Lt](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) | Rep = 1000
- [Lt Cmdr](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) | Rep = 2000
- [Cmdr](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) | Rep = 2500
- [Captain](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) | Rep = 3000
- [Commodore](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) | Rep = 5000
- [Rear Admiral](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) | Rep = 10,000
- [Vice Admiral](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) | Rep = 15,000
- [Admiral](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) | Rep = 20,000
- Fleet Admiral | Moderator

Like I say, this is just a thought and would **NOT** be forced onto people.

## Edit

This idea has been rejected by the community: the reasons for this are explained quite clearly in Wad Cheber's answer below.  I accept the points made in the accepted answer as perfectly valid reasons not to accept this proposal.

Comment: I want to be a Jedi Master!

Comment: Your questions starts with a *non sequitur*. There's no reason a science fiction or fantasy site has to have ranks, naval or otherwise. I think you meant to say, "because this is a Star Trek site . . .".

Comment: @user14111 you have to admit the Star Trek community is pretty strong on this site

Comment: It is sad to see a site, nominally for science fiction and fantasy, overrun by the minions of pop culture franchises. It is another sign of the diminished times we are living in.

Comment: @user14111 well I'm dropping the idea now anyway ;)

Comment: Damn nsoong I'm gonna be a petty office and you'll be a captain. With your 16k and my 3k rep... I'm not taking orders from you no way! Now if I could be a captain for maybe a buck 75, then we're talking. And Richard would be a super admiral, I'm not taking orders from him either, dammit! +1 anyway

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I like the concept, but I don't know how it would work out in execution.  For example, I'm not a fan of *Star Trek*.  I would prefer to have a rank associated with *Star Wars* or *The Lord of the Rings*.  Slytherincess would probably want a rank associated with *Harry Potter*.  Someone else might want a rank associated with Marvel Comics.  Another person would want a rank associated with the *Terminator* franchise.

We'd end up with Maiar, Valar, and Orcs living alongside Wizards and Witches; Jedi and Sith; T-800s and T-1000s; Iron Men, Hulks, and X Men, and so on and so forth.

It would create a huge mess, and it would be totally incomprehensible to new users.

The only way to make it work would be to have people vote for which franchise the titles should be based on, but that would lead to a situation where the people who like the franchise that wins would have titles, but no one else would have one.  That means that the site is now catering to fans of a single franchise, which is not a good thing, at least as I see it.

Comment: You raise quite valid points - the notion is rejected ;)

Comment: @N_Soong great so now I'm gonna be smeagol and you'll be Gandalf, or I'll be Jar Jar Binks and you'll be Vader, no way. And that goes for you too wad I aint taking orders from nobody, lol. +1 anyway

Comment: @WadCheber : These are fair points.  They bring up an interesting question: how did the chat site become Mos Eisley and not, say, Ten Forward or Quark's (the latter two being Star Trek drinking establishments)?

Comment: @Praxis [Because people voted](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/751/what-should-we-call-our-chatroom) on it and Mos Eisley won by a narrow majority.  I admit that I didn't know about this until you asked about it.