# What will we do once the tables have turned?

Tags: discussion, formatting

Tables will be added to the SE network shortly.

[Feature Preview: Table Support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/239016)

Can we identify any posts on our Stack that would benefit from actual tables? I remember seeing quasi-tables being used here and there, but I'm not sure if it was on this Stack.

Let's compile a list of posts with quasi-tables that we can edit to feature actual tables, and stick it in an answer here.

Comment: I am incapable of reading this expression without thinking about [how the turntables.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FwmGLzyRDk)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote [a very basic SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1340650/posts-in-need-of-table-formatting) which is open to improvements; but after excluding the false positives, this draft brings up, at least:

- [Are there any real-life parallels to the Night's Watch and their fall from prestige?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180248/are-there-any-real-life-parallels-to-the-nights-watch-and-their-fall-from-prest)
- <s>[What is the average number of deaths per episode?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58435/what-is-the-average-number-of-deaths-per-episode/212662#212662)</s>
- <s>[Why did other houses not demand this?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/212830/why-did-other-houses-not-demand-this/212863#212863)</s>
- <s>[How many alien women has Capt/Admiral Kirk slept with?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32051/how-many-alien-women-has-capt-admiral-kirk-slept-with/32052#32052)</s>
- [Symbolic meanings of everyone losing their hands?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8555/symbolic-meanings-of-everyone-losing-their-hands/8564#8564)
- [Who was more likely to die, a Death Eater or Order of the Phoenix member?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9446/who-was-more-likely-to-die-a-death-eater-or-order-of-the-phoenix-member/9450#9450)
- <s>[What is the name of the track that plays before the Geth Armature fight on Therum?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155377/what-is-the-name-of-the-track-that-plays-before-the-geth-armature-fight-on-theru)</s>
- [Why are there so many times Harry was told about him having his mother's eyes?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38153/why-are-there-so-many-times-harry-was-told-about-him-having-his-mothers-eyes/38169#38169)
- <s>[Are there any important, extraordinary, or accomplished Hufflepuffs?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11435/are-there-any-important-extraordinary-or-accomplished-hufflepuffs/11476#11476)</s>
- <s>[How are numbers written in the languages of The Lord of the Rings?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/221009/how-are-numbers-written-in-the-languages-of-the-lord-of-the-rings/221401#221401)</s>
- [How many deaths were there on the Enterprise?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102709/how-many-deaths-were-there-on-the-enterprise/102710#102710) (arguably)
- [Can a single player who's been knocked back recover ground?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15097/can-a-single-player-whos-been-knocked-back-recover-ground/15129#15129) (maybe?)
- <s>[How much does the average adult male Dwarf weigh?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53848/how-much-does-the-average-adult-male-dwarf-weigh/74319#74319)</s>
- [Would Aaron encounter the same time-travelling Abe later, if Abe leaves their timeline first?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80706/would-aaron-encounter-the-same-time-travelling-abe-later-if-abe-leaves-their-ti) (maybe?)
- <s>[Does the fantasy genre garner more sequels and series? If so, why?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21704/does-the-fantasy-genre-garner-more-sequels-and-series-if-so-why)</s>
- [How did the duplicate Voyager make it as far as the real Voyager?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32355/how-did-the-duplicate-voyager-make-it-as-far-as-the-real-voyager/142107#142107)
- [How many hands / arms have been cut off in Star Wars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112421/how-many-hands-arms-have-been-cut-off-in-star-wars/112423#112423)
- [How fast could Shadowfax gallop?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39522/how-fast-could-shadowfax-gallop/142271#142271)
- <s>[How many times was Obi-Wan less than honest with Luke?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112540/how-many-times-was-obi-wan-less-than-honest-with-luke/112543#112543)</s>
- <s>[What color is Stormlight?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/147352/what-color-is-stormlight/172233#172233) (or a bullet list, I don't know)</s>
- <s>[How does one pronounce "Asshai"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158981/how-does-one-pronounce-asshai/159025#159025)</s>
- <s>[What is the kill score of all dragons and dragon-riders during the Dance of the Dragons?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/what-is-the-kill-score-of-all-dragons-and-dragon-riders-during-the-dance-of-the/134637#134637)</s>
- <s>[What is a Trial of Seven?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138067/what-is-a-trial-of-seven/138088#138088)</s>
- <s>[Is there any way to make sense out of the scheduling for electives at Hogwarts?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211603/is-there-any-way-to-make-sense-out-of-the-scheduling-for-electives-at-hogwarts/230253#230253)</s>
- <s>[What is the most widespread/numerous alien species in Star Wars (other than Human?)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85602/what-is-the-most-widespread-numerous-alien-species-in-star-wars-other-than-huma/86878#86878)</s>

---

On Meta, based on the same query:

- <s>[Quotes on the site cover how much of the Harry Potter books?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3577/quotes-on-the-site-cover-how-much-of-the-harry-potter-books/3588#3588)</s>
- [Honorary 'Rank' for this site?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7131/honorary-rank-for-this-site) (meh)

---

Taken from [Add support for tables](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2637/add-support-for-tables) (I've removed the duplicates):

- [Who are all the characters to have touched The One Ring?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31610/who-are-all-the-characters-to-have-touched-the-one-ring/31611#31611)
- [What is the chronology of the Gundam series?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8715/what-is-the-chronology-of-the-gundam-series/8717#8717)
- [Fringe: how could September or any other man from the future catch gun bullets in the air?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28746/fringe-how-could-september-or-any-other-man-from-the-future-catch-gun-bullets-i/28748#28748)
- [Community eval — Feb 2013](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2646/community-eval-feb-2013)

---

Additionally (AKA "random encounters", fill up the list as you stumble into them!):

- <s>[How did the cookfire get hot enough to melt gold in Game of Thrones?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28862/how-did-the-cookfire-get-hot-enough-to-melt-gold-in-game-of-thrones/60617#60617)</s>
- [90's PC game, similar to "Another World" but in 3D, dark, purple, locked inside a prison](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/239007/90s-pc-game-similar-to-another-world-but-in-3d-dark-purple-locked-inside)

Comment: Too bad we can't put these in a table.

Comment: @SQB meh, while I do get the meta-joke, a bullet list is more appropriate here: once we start editing them, we can edit this post as well with strikethroughs, which will be easier on the eye than a done/Not done table

Comment: It may be worth knowing that ["You can't merge cells or rows"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) on the new tables, which makes the first post on your list (https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180248/are-there-any-real-life-parallels-to-the-nights-watch-and-their-fall-from-prest) a bit awkward to convert.

Comment: @SQB (and future editors) shouldn't we keep the link even for handled ones?

Comment: @Jenayah yeah, it's a bit of a formatting snafu. In preview, the link shows up formatted, but in the actual post, it does not. I'll file a bug. EtA: [there already is one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351092/239016); a space between the `<s>` and the link (and after it) fixes it.

Comment: The year in moderation posts from the past should also probably be done.